# É possível criar um objeto/class/interface que represente um assinatura de uma function?

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions

Tudo já funciona como esperado em meu código. O que estou querendo é torna-lo mais verboso, fazendo com que as assinaturas do método sejam mais auto-explicativas (sei que posso utilizar comentários Docs para isso, mais gostaria de também utilizar os tipos do **TypeScript**) e possam ser melhor validadas pelos [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/)'s da vida.

O que tenho hoje:

```
class Test{
    testMetadada<T>(expression: (t: T) => void) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

O objeto `expression` é do tipo `(t: T) => void`, o que não é muito explicativo, gostaria por exemplo que fosse possível algo como:

```
class Expression<T> extends (t: T) => void{

}
```

ou

```
interface Expression<T> extends (t: T) => void{

}
```

ou

```
let Expression = ((t: T) => void)<T>;
```

Para que meu método fosse algo como:

```
class Test{
    testMetadada<T>(expression: Expression) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Onde `Expression` representasse a mesma function `(t: T) => void`.

Há algo que possa fazer nesse sentido?

> Veja [aqui o exemplo do que estou tentando implementar com isso](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Class1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Class2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clazz1%3A%20Class1%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Class3%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop3%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clazz2%3A%20Class2%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testMetadada%3CT%3E(expression%3A%20(t%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.getPropertiesByExpression(expression))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20getPropertiesByExpression(expression%3A%20(x)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20strAfterReturn%20%3D%20expression.toString().split(%22return%22)%5B1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20strBeforeSemicon%20%3D%20strAfterReturn.split(%22%3B%22)%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20propertiesReferences%20%3D%20strBeforeSemicon.split(%22.%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20propertiesReferences.shift()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20propertiesReferences%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass1%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass2%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz1.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass3%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz2.clazz1.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass3%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz2.prop2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20h1%20%3D%20document.createElement('h1')%3B%0D%0Ah1.textContent%20%3D%20%22See%20console!%20%3AD%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(h1)%3B) (a possibilidade de utilizar [**`Arrow function`** do **TypeScript**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) como expressões [**Lambda Expressions** do **C#**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) para obter metadados)

Comment: Gostei da pergunta. Acho que eu posso pensar em algo se você der um exemplo mais "palpável", eu não consegui entender bem o queres fazer.

Comment: @LINQ, pois bem, o que pretendo não é nada funcional, é apenas poder criar um Tipo, que presente a parâmetro Function. Olhando agora isso parece ser algo um pouco confuso mesmo. Não sei bem como ter algo mais "palpável". Olhou o exemplo? O que não está claro para você? Se puder me questionar sobre os pontos que não entendeu do meu objetivo?

Comment: @LINQ, veja, o que quero é tornar o tipo `(t: T) => void` do parâmetro do método `testMetadada` um Tipo realmente no **Typescript**, isso poderia ser através de um Objeto, Class ou Interface. Será que melhorou?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível utilizar [*type aliases*:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases)

```
type Expression<T> = (t: T) => void;
```

Ficando assim a assinatura do método:

```
class Test{
    testMetadada<T>(expression: Expression<T>) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

> [Exemplo atualizado da solução.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Class1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Class2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clazz1%3A%20Class1%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Class3%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop3%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clazz2%3A%20Class2%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Expression%3CT%3E%20%3D%20(t%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testMetadada%3CT%3E(expression%3A%20Expression%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.getPropertiesByExpression(expression))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20getPropertiesByExpression%3CT%3E(expression%3A%20Expression%3CT%3E)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20strAfterReturn%20%3D%20expression.toString().split(%22return%22)%5B1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20strBeforeSemicon%20%3D%20strAfterReturn.split(%22%3B%22)%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20propertiesReferences%20%3D%20strBeforeSemicon.split(%22.%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20propertiesReferences.shift()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20propertiesReferences%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass1%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass2%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz1.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass3%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz2.clazz1.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass3%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz2.prop2)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass3%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz2.clazz1)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20h1%20%3D%20document.createElement('h1')%3B%0D%0Ah1.textContent%20%3D%20%22See%20console!%20%3AD%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(h1)%3B)

---

> Baseado na [resposta a essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45167542/2290538).